# Where do you put your third party themes folder? has a community consensus been discussed?

Tags: add-on, bestpractice, themes

I've recently started to use PATH_THIRD_THEMES in my config file, but i was wondering if there was a community consensus on where this folder should live and be called?

/assets/third_themes
/assets/addons
/third_party_themes
etc

Comment: This is a question that's more opinion-based rather than has one specific answer.

Answer (score 3):

I've not seen or heard any chatter about this, but I definitely prefer to keep all directories and files which shouldn't be replaced during an EE upgrade in my /assets directory like this.

**If I can place /system below root** I leave the system third_party directory there for better security.

**If I can't place /system below the root...**

Third party /system files:

```
/assets/third_party/system/
```

**Always**

Third party /themes files:

```
/assets/third_party/themes/
```

Master config settings:

```
$env_config['path_third_themes']   = $base_path . '/assets/third_party/themes/';
$env_config['url_third_themes']    = $base_url . '/assets/third_party/themes/';
/* If system directory is not below root, uncomment and ensure directory exists */
// $env_config['third_party_path']    = $base_path . '/assets/third_party/system/';
```

Answer (score 0):

At the moment there are too many 3rd party addons that seem to need their theme files to be in /themes/third_party so using a custom location isn't fool proof. With that in mind I personally like to keep as many things as "default" as possible.

Comment: I've not experienced any add-ons that need a hard-coded path. They usually (and hopefully) all read EE config settings.